# Need to restart apache if apache connection exceeds X amount

Tags: linux, bash, apache

I'm creating a bash script in which whenever my apache exceeds a fixed amount of numbers then it restart itself on next cronjob. I've created something but it is not running properly.

```
#!/bin/bash
RESTART="systemctl restart httpd"
COUNT="ps aux | grep httpd | wc -l"
SERVICE="httpd"
LOGFILE="/opt/httpd/autostart-apache2.log"



if COUNT > 45
then
echo "starting apache at $(date)" >> $LOGFILE
$RESTART >> $LOGFILE
else
echo "apache is running at $(date)"
fi
```

The error it is throwing is

```
line 10: COUNT: command not found
apache is running at Sat Sep 10 23:34:30 IST 2022
```

Can anyone help me on how to store the value of the output of `ps aux | grep httpd | wc -l` as a number and compare it with another number.

Comment: `> 45` Created a file named `45`. Paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation, suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

- `RESTART="systemctl restart httpd"` is a variable assignment, although it might work for your use case, you should really use a function instead. See the [Complex](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) page for more info.
- `COUNT="ps aux | grep httpd | wc -l"` is a variable assignment as well use [Command Substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002), like what you did with `$(date)`, on a side note [grep](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) has the `-c` option, there is no need for `wc`.
- `COUNT > 45` You're executing the `COUNT` word/string but since there is nothing in your script/path/function/executable with the same name (`COUNT` is a variable name in your script), thus you get the error: `line 10: COUNT: command not found`

  - `>` is a form of [redirection](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Redirection) if not used in [Arithmetic Expression.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression), it truncates a file or create it if it does not exists. Like in your code `> 45` created a file named `45`. Open the file for writing is the proper term word for it according to the bash manual.

---

Here is how I would write it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

service="httpd"
count="$(ps aux | grep -c "$service")"
logfile="/opt/httpd/autostart-apache2.log"
restart(){ systemctl restart  "$service" ; }

if (( count > 45 )); then
  echo "starting apache at $(date)" >> "$logfile"
  restart >> "$logfile" 2>&1
else
  echo "apache is running at $(date)"
fi
```

---

- `(( count > 45 ))` is a form of [test](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) in bash for comparing/testing numbers. The `$` can be omitted inside it.